# unable to validate DateType

Tags: symfony, symfony-validator

Here's what I have:

In my route I create a default entity. "startdate" and "enddate", both date objects.

```
/**
 * @Route("/vacature/nieuw", name="create_vacancy")
 */
public function createVacancyAction(Request $request)
{
    $vacancy = new Vacancy();
    $vacancy->setStartdate(new \DateTime())
        ->setEnddate(new \DateTime());
    $form = $this->createForm(VacancyType::class, $vacancy);

    // check if valid and persist or whatever
}
```

In my VacancyType I set the date constraint for both my date fields like so:

```
->add("startdate", DateType::class, array(
            "widget" => "single_text",
            "constraints" => array(
                new Date(array(
                    "message" => "vacancy.date.message"
                )),
                new GreaterThanOrEqual("today")
            )
        ))
```

The dates are pre-filled in html in a yyyy-mm-dd format which is how I want them to.

Then, without editing the html field I receive this error upon submitting the form:
[image]

Comment: You say the dates are pre-filled with a valid format, but the field returns the string "startdate" instead of an actual date. Can you show us the HTML code where you inject the date into the field?

Comment: It's all done by symfony in my Controller/Route. please see my code above.. I create a form with a default instance $vacancy, which has 2 fields set via the setter in my route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found it! seemed I tried the constraint **new GreaterThanOrEqual("startdate")**. Thinking it would refer to my startdate....sadly it doesn not :(